# Ubuntu 14.04 and RaspberryPi 2, help me understand how it works

Tags: 14.04, kernel, raspberrypi

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

So Ubuntu has a ARMv7 package builds, but not kernel specific for the RaspberryPi 2. It says, currently the community is maintaining the kernel.

- What does this entail?
- How often are kernel updates released?
- Is there a "generic" kernel that would work on the pi (for a server, I don't care about hardware acceleration of video or even having audio)?

Comment: Ubuntu Mate is probably easier and maintained by someone for the rpi2, which is basically ubuntu with the mate desktop. https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/

Comment: Ah interesting, I wonder if I can uninstall the ui...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work with generic kernel. It needs some firmware.

This specific stuff is in the PPA. It's sometimes updated. There is also an image creation script on that wiki. And a resulting image too.

To get a working SD image for Pi 2, you have to build a Pi-specific kernel package (using the source code from the rpi branch) and assemble several kernel-related packages (by putting together some slightly altered standard things and also downloading binary packages with Pi firmware/video driver).

So, there are 3 possibilities:

- use the pre-built image (use image from that wiki or use Ubuntu Mate image and remove some UI/network manager packages)
- use pre-built Pi-specific packages from PPA and generate an image with the script (so now the package set of the image is customizable)
- use raw materials: build Pi-specific packages from sources, generate an image (in this case you decide when to update the kernel by merging/rebasing the rpi branch into the latest kernel version and rebuilding; you also decide when to repack the firmware)

**update**

Supporting raspberry images is painful. They haven't pushed all of their kernel stuff to upstream, the binary blobs don't look good either. Unity can't work with the video driver of raspberry (Unity needs a real OpenGL).

Your instructions for Ubuntu Mate just for backup here:

```
sudo apt-get -y --purge autoremove mate-* ubuntu-mate-* xcursor-themes xdg-utils xinput xorg-docs-core xul-ext-ubufox xauth libxrandr2 ^libqt.* libportaudio2 libopenjpeg5 libmp3lame0  libgtk* gnome* xorg  xserver-common libwayland-client0 libwayland-server0 libwebcam0 libvlc5 ^qtcore4-.* duplicity xterm lightdm x11-common ^libxcb-.* ^libx.*  avahi-dnsconfd libfontenc1 python-xlib libpixman-1-0 xbitmaps ubuntu-sounds youtube-dl yelp-xsl  sound-theme-freedesktop samba-common atril-common

sudo apt-get -y --purge autoremove ^bluez.* brasero-common  ^caja-.* crda ^cups.* dvd+rw-tools eom-common ^fontconfig.* ^fonts-.* ^foomatic.* growisofs ^gsettings.* ^gstreamer.* iw jackd2 ^libasound2.* libavutil-ffmpeg54 ^libcups.* libcdparanoia0 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 ^libfreerdp.* libgphoto2-l10n ^libgs9.* ^libgstreamer.* libiw30 libjack-jackd2-0 libjasper1

sudo apt-get -y --purge autoremove ^libjpeg.* ^libmtp.* libogg0 libotr5 libpng12-0 libplank-common ^libreoffice.* libtiff5 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop libwebp5 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 ^libwinpr-.* marco-common  media-player-info oem-config-gtk oem-config openprinting-ppds ^printer-driver-.*

sudo apt-get -y --purge autoremove  python-boto python-caja-common python-cloudfiles  python-codebug-i2c-tether python-codebug-tether  python-colorama python-astropi python-html5lib python-picamera python-sense-hat

sudo apt-get -y --purge autoremove python3-picamera python3-markupsafe  python3-pil qtchooser rfkill shotwell-common wpasupplicant wireless-regdb vlc-data avahi-autoipd uvcdynctrl-data libhtml-parser-perl   libhtml-tagset-perl  python3-html5lib python3-markupsafe pluma-common atril-common engrampa-common menu-xdg  desktop-file-utils  gir1.2-freedesktop hicolor-icon-theme  policykit-desktop-privileges python-xdg  python3-xdg gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 alsa-base linux-sound-base

sudo apt-get -y install deborphan
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove $(deborphan)
```

Comment: Thanks! I took the Ubuntu Mate image and removed the desktop packages (a LOT of trial and error). 

Why doesn't Ubuntu put out an image for this device? Snappy is a cool concept, but "it just ain't there".

Comment: And for anyone else going down this path... here's all the packages I uninstalled: http://pastebin.com/ij1ia0DB